# Java stream of class ancestors

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How to create a `Stream` of class ancestors?

What I can do is:

```
public static Stream<Class<?>> streamOfAncestors(Class<?> klass) {
    ArrayList<Class<?>> ancestorsList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        klass = klass.getSuperclass();
        if (klass == null) {
            return ancestorsList.stream();
        } else {
            ancestorsList.add(klass);
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not elegant and my stream is not lazy. How to make a lazy `Stream`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `Stream.iterate()`. You'll have to combine it with `takeWhile` (introduced in Java 9) in order to make the `Stream` finite.

```
public static Stream<Class<?>> streamOfAncestors(Class<?> klass) {
    return Stream.iterate (klass.getSuperclass(), k -> k != null ? k.getSuperclass() : null)
                 .takeWhile(Objects::nonNull);
}
```

Or, if you don't want to use Java 9 features, you can write a method similar to `Stream.iterate()`, but make it produce a finite `Stream`:

```
public static Stream<Class<?>> streamOfAncestors(Class<?> klass) {
    final Iterator<Class<?>> iterator = new Iterator<Class<?>>() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<?> k = klass.getSuperclass ();

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return k != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> next() {
            Class<?> curr = k;
            k = k.getSuperclass ();
            return curr;
        }
    };
    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
            iterator,
            Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.IMMUTABLE), false);
}
```

Sample execution of the second method:

```
streamOfAncestors (StringBuilder.class).forEach (System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
class java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder
class java.lang.Object
```

EDIT:

As Holger commented, all of this is not necessary if you are using Java 9, which has a [Stream.iterate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) variant that produces a finite `Stream`.

All you need to write is:

```
public static Stream<Class<?>> streamOfAncestors(Class<?> klass) {
    return Stream.iterate (klass.getSuperclass(), Objects::nonNull, Class::getSuperclass);
}
```

Comment: Whenever you feel tempted to chain `takeWhile` to `iterate`, remember the three-arg `iterate` method, also introduced in Java 9, i.e. `Stream.iterate(klass, Objects::nonNull, Class::getSuperclass)`. And, as often, implementing a `Spliterator` directly turns out to be simpler than implementing and wrapping an `Iterator` (see the dup link)…

Comment: @Holger Thanks. I was surprised I didn't find a `Stream.iterate()` variant for a finite Stream in Java 8, and didn't think to check if they added one in Java 9 (I should probably install Java 9 on my machine...).